# Easy program for technical draw?

Tags: drawing, technical-drawing

I would like to ask you, which program for technical draw (for non-graphic people) is most suitable? It should be quite easy to understand... it is for my older colleagues at work. :-) Thank you for your advice!

**E.**

[image]

Comment: Cad applications arent really in scope for this site. Easy tu understand is relative to what you know. Rhino, LibreCAD? maybe. Personally I find that a constraint based system is easier if you bother to spend a hour thinking before first use.

Comment: No matter what you choose, there's going to be a learning curve with software. There's no such thing as "easy" for technical drawings.

Answer (score 1):

There are many more criteria that need to be known to properly answer this-

Is this a single drawing you need or are there more that will need to be done ? How much are you willing to have to learn about the workings of a program to make this drawing ? Does this drawing need to be to scale ?( assuming yes).

I would suggest a vector drawing program-

Obviously a CAD drawing program is best suited for this- but a very steep learning curve and costly.

Inkscape (free) or Adobe Illustrator ($$) could certainly do this but have a definite learning curve. If scale is needed then you would have to do this with your own calculations (drawing to scale is not an inherit part of these programs).

I have a very simple drawing program called "Shapes" (for Mac only) which is very easy to use/ learn and quite inexpensive. There are probably lots of programs like this that could easily make this drawing. Again, scale would be a challenge- you would have to create your own scale to input to the program.

Unless you or someone on your team really wants to invest the time and the money to learn how to use a vector drawing program, then I suggest you simply hire someone with the proper tools and the proper knowledge to do this drawing for you.